# How can I establish a TCP connection between several computers behind two firewalls?

Tags: networking, tcp

I'd like to establish several TCP connections between computers behind a firewall.

The follow picture illustrates a simple network:

[Firewalled Network http://img35.imageshack.us/img35/1545/firewallgf.png](http://img35.imageshack.us/img35/1545/firewallgf.png)

From the picture I'd like to establish 3 TCP connections:

```
A => 2
B => 2
C => 2
```

What are my options for establishing these TCP connections?

and

Can I do this without port forwarding?

Answer (score 1):

You could have some server in the cloud acting as a proxy for your connections. For instance, think about how a service like LogMeIn or GoToMyPC manages connections between a client and the controlled host. This is one idea.

Answer (score 1):

This should be an interesting read.

[How does Skype work without port forwarding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1539339/how-skype-work-without-port-forwarding)

Comment: After you read through all that, it leads to a very detailed explanation at http://www.h-online.com/security/features/How-Skype-Co-get-round-firewalls-747197.html