# Chat program without a central server

Tags: security, chat

I'm developing a chat application (in VB.Net). It will be a "secure" chat program. All traffic will be encrypted (I also need to find the best approach for this, but that's not the question for now).

Currently the program works. I have a server application and a client application. However I want to setup the application so that it doesn't need a central server for it to work.

What approach can I take to decentralize the network?

I think I need to develop the clients in a way so that they do also act as a server.

How would the clients know what server it needs to connect with / what happens if a server is down? How would the clients / servers now what other nodes there are in the network without having a central server?

At best I don't want the clients to know what the IP addresses are of the different nodes, however I don't think this would be possible without having a central server.

As stated the application will be written in VB.Net, but I think the language doesn't really matter at this point.

Just want to know the different approaches I can follow.

Comment: Closely related: [How skype works without port forwarding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1539339/how-skype-work-without-port-forwarding)

Comment: Although it was an interesting read I don't think (if I understand it correctly) that it is really related. Skype tries to send the message to the destination (which are multiple destinations in a chat session e.g. everyone who is connected). To do this the client would need to know all different addresses which I want to prevent. Second skype uses a central server which holds all different addresses which uses if client A can not directly connect to client B, which is also I'm trying to prevent. Please tell me if I understood the skype post wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look for example at the paper of the Kademlia protocol ([you can find it here](http://pdos.csail.mit.edu/~petar/papers/maymounkov-kademlia-lncs.pdf)). If you just want a quick overview, look at the Wikipedia page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kademlia. The Kademlia protocol defines a way of node lookups in a network in a decentral way. It has been successfully applied in the eMule software - so it is tested to really work.

It should cause no serious problems to apply it to your chat software.

Comment: @PeeHaa, did this indeed provide you with what you needed to create a decentralised chat program? The link is no longer working and I am trying to create a chat program without a central server also. Might you be able to point me in the right direction?

Comment: @Totem Yeah link only answers suck for this very reason. This answer (including the link) did help me though. A related paper is http://maude.sip.ucm.es/kademlia/files/pita_kademlia.pdf. TL;DR it defines a way of node lookups in a network in a decentral way. For a quick intro http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kademlia

Comment: I updated the link in my post to a working link to a Kademlia paper.

Comment: @PeeHaa This looks like the stuff alright. I was previously looking around at talk of a bittorrent chat program that was based on bit sync, and hoping the bit sync api would help me out, but so far haven't found how It would.

Answer (score 3):

You need *some* known IP address for clients to initially get into a network. Once a client is part of a network, things can be more decentralized, but that first step needs something.

There are basically only two options - either the user provides one (for an existing node of the network - essentially how BitTorrent trackers work), or you hard-code in a gateway node (which is effectively a central server).

Comment: The hard-code approach is not an option because when the server gets down the whole network will fail (if I understand you right). I was indeed thinking about a P2P way of doing it. But how would the application know what nodes there are in the network without letting the user get all other nodes in the network. So that people won't be able retrieve all addresses in the network. How to setup it up without a central server in a way that multiple servers are allowed on the network?

Comment: Usually you'd have some form of identifier (say, username), and each node maintains a routing table for usernames. The routing table doesn't have end IPs for each user, but instead just the address of a neighbor in the network who already has an entry for that user. Thus, A's routing table for 'foo' might point to B, and B's routing table for 'foo' might point to C, and C's routing table for 'foo' points to D, where D is the actual machine that 'foo' is logged in from. Thus A doesn't know D's ip - only C knows that. A would send messages to B, which would forward them to C, who forwards to D.

Comment: Note that this routing table maps **usernames to abstract IPs** in exactly the same way that the Internet maps **IPs to abstract physical locations**. This also means that it has the same issues as the Internet itself - the weak point is with whatever authority you use to enforce uniqueness for identifiers. In the case of the Internet, this is ISPs; in the case of a chat client, this is whatever login server you use. One way to get around this is to use public keys for identification, and encrypt all traffic with those keys, which doesn't enforce uniqueness but makes it hard to exploit.

Comment: It is indeed essentially the way Tor operates (but Tor still uses known server IPs for your initial entry into the Tor network).

Comment: @Amber `The routing table doesn't have end IPs for each user, but instead just the address of a neighbor in the network who already has an entry for that user.` What would happen if the neighbor disconnects. The client would be cut off from the network (incl. all other clients behind the client). Which would result in a split network. How to prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can see uChat program. It's a program from uTorrent creator with chat without server in mind.

The idea is connect to a swarm from a magnetlink and use it to send an receive messages. This is as Amber answer, you need an access point, may it be a server, a know swarm, manual ip, etc.

Here is uChat presentation: http://blog.bittorrent.com/2011/06/30/uchat-we-just-need-each-other/